# Get HTML from CURRENT aspx-Page to String Value (Codebehind)

Tags: asp.net, html, c#-4.0, ckeditor

I am currently developing a page which is (nearly) fully inline-editable with CKEditor. So after the user has finished editing I want to get the plain HTML Code, remove the editor controls and send the result via eMail. This disqualifies the WebRequest-Method as this "reloads" the page. Is there an option to get the CURRENT html from the page in a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have to do this by AJAX. Get the contents of the HTML to a JavaScript variable, then POST the variable to your backend (where you now have the WebRequest). Try something like this if you use jQuery:

```
var markup = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
alert("Submitting: " + markup"); // big alert...

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "path/to/HTML_handler.aspx",
    data: { html: markup }
})
.done(function(msg) {
    alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
});
```

Then in your backend read the posted html variable a vomit it into a backend.

---

**Edit 11.9.2014**

I'm an MVC guy myself, but the classic ASP.net way of doing this I think is something like this: in your aspx view, add a button, such as this: `<button id="Derp">I love ponies</button>`. Add a reference to jQUery: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` (I'm using the Google CDN here). Then bind a click event to the button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var btn = $('#Derp');
        btn.click(function() {
            var markup = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
            alert("Submitting...");

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "AJAXRequest.ashx", // Important that this points to the right file...
                data: { html: markup }
            })
            .done(function(msg) {
                alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then create a backend handler (Google for more tutorials) that goes something like this:

AJAXRequest.asgx (yeah, just one line):

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" CodeBehind="AJAXRequest.ashx.cs" Class="WebApplication1.AJAXRequest" %>
```

AJAXRequest.ashx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class AJAXRequest : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            // Not sure which one to use here, try both
            string html1 = context.Request["html"];
            string html2 = context.Request.Form["html"];

            // Do whatever you want with the html...

            context.Response.Write("OMG I just found: " + html1);
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Yeah, this code is very much untested, but I think you get the gist of it.

Comment: If you can't use jQuery just use native JavaScript, it works fine too but I can't be bothered to write an example because jQuery <3.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've never worked with jQuery nor JavaScript. How do i wrap your code in the .aspx-file? And how can I get the posted markup in Codebehind?
Edit: And how can i run this script in ButtonClick?

Comment: I added an edit, can you check it out? If you want to contain it in  one aspx file to process the request inside a script block fired by a ButtonClick or something, you'll have to figure that out by Googling around - it seems like bad practice to me. Most likely you can do it, but I really don't recommend it. Maybe you will find an ASPX guru that can do it with a postback or a partial AJAX call made by the ASP framework, but to me that sounds... wrong.

Comment: Thanks for this very useful answer. I get a ParseError: `The directive 'webhandler' is unknown.` Have I missed something? Google research doesn't deliver solutions. Thanks again, and sorry for my derpness